# Add product to quote when not in stock

Tags: magento2, quote

I am trying to create a quote programmaticaly via

```
$quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
$quote->addProduct($item);
```

But it does not allow me to add a product that is not in stock: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): This product is out of stock.

How can I bypass this check? I don't need to finish the order.

```
$stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
```

is of no use if I am not saving it. And I don't want to save it because it is not supposed to change.

Comment: you need to skip the stock validation at "addProduct" method in module-checkout\Model\Cart.php and you need to override this method

Comment: But when I override the Cart Model, isn't it for the whole store then? I only need to skip the validation in this exact moment. I don't call the cart, I only create a quote, add a product, get the shipping costs and thats it.

Comment: I think without touch this method we can't skip stock validation.